# Purpose of the size() method in ArrayList

Tags: java, list

Is the `size()` method the `ArrayList` class simply a getter, or does it perform any sort of calculation?

If it is a getter then is it safe to assume that it will be inlined at some point if I call it a large number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if there's any overhead in calling "size()", the answer is "No".

Here's a similar discussion on a similar method, String.length():

[In Java, for a string x, what is the runtime cost of s.length()? Is it O(1) or O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254726/in-java-for-a-string-x-what-is-the-runtime-cost-of-s-length-is-it-o1-or-o)

The answer in both cases - String.length() and ArrayList.size() - is "O(1)".

Answer (score 1):

`size()` method is not a standard setter/getter, it is a method of `List` which is defined to give the size of the `list` (number of elements)

`ArrayList` implements it by following way

```
 public int size() {
  230           return size;
  231       }
```

it maintains a `int` variable called `size`, when we add it increases, decreases on removal.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not `ArrayList.size()` will ever be inlined depends on a number of factors, but, yes, at least in theory if you reference `size()` enough times and if all the other inlining criteria are met then it will be inlined.

For the most part ArrayList is just a class, not unlike a class that you might write.  So it would be subject to the same inlining rules/potential.

[Just checked the source for ArrayList and here is what I found:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Which is about as vanilla (and highly inline-able) as you can get.  So I'd say that `size()` will inline in virtually all cases where you don't seriously obscure the class type somehow.]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to truly see for yourself how the *size()* method is implemented, you may download the source for the java library as it is under the GNU GPL; line 196 in the OpenJDK 6 sources.

[OpenJDK 7 Sources](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/)

On the topic of *inlining*, you may wish to read the following post:

[Inlining in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159087/inlining-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Since the getter is just returning a a field, there is no negative performance impact. The JIT is smart enough to inline the call so that you dont have the function call overhead.

See similar question here: [Is ArrayList.size() method cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856835/is-arraylist-size-method-cached)